# Meaning of "short of" within "He doesn't trust the president to respect the results of any election short of an overwhelming defeat"

Tags: meaning-in-context

If I understood the meaning of "short of" correctly, this sentence :

> "He doesn't trust the president to respect the results of any election short of an overwhelming defeat"

would mean :

> "He doesn't trust the president to respect the results of any election whose result will be anything less than overwhelming defeat"

But this statement sounds rather strange, doesn't ?

Comment: What sounds strange about it?

Comment: @Juhasz, my bad, with hindsight, I think that  indented meaning is that if the president must be defeated, then it needs to be done with an overwhelming defeat, otherwise he won't accept his defeat, correct ?

Comment: Yep, you've got it.